# Why is PutItem on dynamodb table generating AccessDeniedException error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We have these aws lambdas that are inserting dynamodb records into replicated dynamodb tables. All these lambdas share the same iam execution role that gives them full access to dynamodb tables. All the replicated tables are configured the same. We are using kms encryption on both sides in master and replicated tables. One of these lambdas can insert into one of these replicated tables, but another lambda using same execution role cannot insert into another table. Is generating this error:

AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxx:assumed-role/CSSLambdaDynamoDBSQS/EscrowWarrantyDevLambda is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxx:table/EscrowWarranty    at Request.extractError....

Not sure why this error is happening when inserting to this one table. All lambdas using same execution role.

Comment: Are all of your DynamoDB tables tables in the same region?  Looks like you are using us-east-2.

Comment: KMS permissions are also given to the functions?

Comment: All the replicated tables are in us-east-2 region. The master tables are in us-west-2. The KMS policy gives encrypt/decrypt perm for the execution role. Need to check if kms perm added to lambda function. The west lambda functions work fine with master tables. All lambdas use same role.